# Unity CanvasGroup's alpha is set to 0 when Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a prefab holding a CanvasGroup component inside. When I instantiate it, its alpha becomes 0 even though in the prefab it is set to 1.

```
RemoteDiffMenu remoteDiffPrefab = Resources.Load<RemoteDiffMenu>("Prefabs/Utils/UI/RemoteDiff");
RemoteDiffMenu remoteDiff = Instantiate(remoteDiffPrefab, transform);
```

It is instantiated under another CanvasGroup by the way.

[image]

**Both SettingsMenu and RemoteDiff hold a CanvasGroup**

RemoteDiff's Canvas Group:

[image: RemoteDiff's Canvas Group]

Comment: What if you select the 'IgnoreParentGroups' checkbox in your prefab?

Comment: Nope. Didn't work :S

Comment: From the info provided, it's possible that RemoteDiffMenu script sets the alpha to 0 somewhere, or some other component (like a parent object) is setting this alpha to 0. (The prefab is set to alpha 1, but something else is causing it to become 0 during or after instantiation.) I think you may want to post more code or narrow down your problem so it's more [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).